# How can I turn off all write and sanitize features on an SSD?

Tags: ssd

Is it possible to somehow download the embedded disk bios and hack it or is there a way of switching some stuff around on the hardware itself to make it very annoying to run the disk santizing feature or to prevent any further writes to the disk ?

On the hardware itself.
Not the os.

Comment: No. But maybe you could explain your actual problem.

Comment: just that I want to make it impossible to destroy files on a disk without destroying the disk itself. on an ssd

Comment: I understand there to be a way to hack the firmware of ssds as well

Comment: I accepted the answer is accepted because it indicates something blocking actual ownership of my own device trusting the manufacturer to protect me against a hacker

Comment: I don’t know what’s worse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firmware is digitally signed and cannot be hacked.

If your problem is verifying that the files can only be written by yourself,
you may encrypt them using a tool such as
[PGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy).

You will be encrypting the files using your private key that you keep secret,
and will communicate only your public key, with which the files may be
decrypted (but not encrypted).

For more information, see for example one of the many articles:
[A Deep Dive on End-to-End Encryption: How Do Public Key Encryption Systems Work?](https://ssd.eff.org/en/module/deep-dive-end-end-encryption-how-do-public-key-encryption-systems-work)